# Cannot implicitly convert type System.data.datatable to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#

```
 public DataTable populateVendorGridView()
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = (DataSet)Session["VendorInvoiceid"];

            return ds.Tables[0]; //getting error here
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked Dataset instance?

Comment: Can you please post the result of this code from the debugger: `ds.Tables.Count`

Answer (score 4):

a `DataTable` type exists in both namespaces:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

and

```
System.Data
```

which are imported into your file.

You have to explicitly reference the correct namespace for the return type of `populateVendorGridView`:

```
public System.Data.DataTable populateVendorGridView()
{
    ...
```